# API 404 error using C#

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm trying create a simple API and call it from my html. I made something similar earlier today but I can't get this one to work. It just returns a 404 error.

script from HTML

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                    var uri = 'api/books';
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $.getJSON(uri)
                            .done(function (data) {
                                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                                    $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#books'));
                                });
                            });
                    });
```

api controller

```
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{

    public class BookController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/books")]
        public IHttpActionResult ShowAllProducts()
        {
            var db = new DbSearchQuery();
            return Ok(db.LoadBooks());
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:

WebApiConfig.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that your route looks like `host/api/api/Book`. Try to remove your first slug `api` in annotation for action method. Well, you can check your requests in browser dev tools so.

Comment: You are sure your LoadBooks return correct json? According to the jquery documentation: `As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently`

Comment: I am fairly certain, because I created another proof of concept Solution in which I pulled this from the same data base were the Query was the exact same. I just added the same api controller and jquery to another solution where this api will be used.

Comment: @suavocado Check URL of your GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `relative to root`paths. You missing a backslash in your uri. Change `uri` as following :

```
var uri = '/api/books';
```

and make sure you have `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your `WebApiConfig.Register()` method.

EDIT 1

You can view the details of network errors ( like 404 ) in console section of your browser's developer tools. Just hit F12 in your browser to activate developer tools window and take a look at console tab. You'll probably see that your ajax call targeting a different location than `www.yoursite.com/api/books`

Comment: @suavocado make sure your application is running ( check that url in browser ) and can you verify that you are making the ajax request within the same url ( just to rule out the cors problems )

Answer (score 1):

Start by changing your controller code:

```
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/books")]
    public class BookController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult ShowAllProducts()
        {
            var db = new DbSearchQuery();
            return Ok(db.LoadBooks());
        }

    }

}
```

Then double check that your Ajax call is made to the correct address: `http://yourhost/api/books` looking at your browser console.

[Edit after comments]

Please check if your project contains a startup class. If you are using Owin then you have to create a `Startup.cs` file for bootstrapping your application. A basic example can be found below:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
   }
}
```

More about how to start Owin based web application here [What is the new Startup.cs file for in Visual Studio 2013 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034105/what-is-the-new-startup-cs-file-for-in-visual-studio-2013-projects)

Comment: Ajax call is going to the correct http://..../api/books and has been, but still getting the the 404

Comment: Can you add your Startup.cs and WebApiConfig.cs code?

Comment: Just added it, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please post also your Startup.cs file, with the current code I have no other suggestions for you.

Comment: I looked through my solution explorer and didn't find any Startup.cs file

Comment: Edited the answer after your last comments

Comment: Fixed the solution it was an issue with the startup.cs thanks man

Answer (score 0):

added Global.aspx

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
}
```